# Can we make an application to process and fill data in 2 excel files using 1 formula file?

Tags: excel

(Excel)

1. so I have 1 formula file
2. This formula file, has been logically organized to process 2 types of data files
3. I want the process to be done automatically
4. So I just need to enter 2 data files into the app
5. and the output is 2 types of data files, already processed and filled in
6. So I can use the application for the same type of data but different values

could it happen? what kind of application is suitable?
sorry if my English is bad :)

Comment: Doesn't make sense. You may need VBA macro to do so.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Try to use more than one sentence that goes on and on forever and is so hard to read that when you get to the end of the sentence you cannot really remember what words were used to start it and how the problem was described before it veered off into incomprehenisble sidelines that lost all connection to the topic. Instead, keep it short. Describe the input. Describe the desired output. Describe the logic that leads to the output. And, most importantly: Post what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: im sorry, im using translator to ask the question in english maybe thats make the words ambiguous

Comment: i try to rearrange my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can use VBA and in the Macro specify each Workbook you need to update
2. The better option is to use PowerQuery and M Language: you can use the formulas and the connections to make sure that both Workbooks are updated.

For further information about Power Query:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-power-query-in-excel-7104fbee-9e62-4cb9-a02e-5bfb1a6c536a

https://www.howtoexcel.org/the-complete-guide-to-power-query/

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer, gonna try every option that u've been recommend :)